# VBS Copy and Rename A File Error

Tags: vbscript, copy, move

I have a file downloaded to TEMP which needs to copied to Firefox directory.
However, I keep getting this error.

> Error: Bad file name or number`
>   Code: 800A0034

```
oFSO.MoveFile "C:\TEMP\Firefox\update.log", """C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\uninstall\uninstall.update""" '// Rename file`
```

I am using three set of quotes, because two wasn't working. Using two quotes gives the following error

> Expected end of statement
>   Code: 800A401`

Comment: Not sure why you are escaping the quotes it is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the use of `"""`. The destination location doesn't need to have escaped `"` characters around it.

If you change it to the following, I've tested and confirmed it works:

```
oFSO.MoveFile "C:\TEMP\Firefox\update.log", "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\uninstall\uninstall.update"
```

Answer (score 0):

try the old 8.3 naming convention

```
oFSO.MoveFile "C:\TEMP\Firefox\update.log", "C:\Progra~1\Mozill~1\uninstall\uninstall.update" '// Rename file
```

Comment: That will work but it isn't the cause of the issue. It's the fact the quotes aren't being escaped that makes it work, both 8.3 and LFN convention both work the same way.